# Is this a PHP relative date bug?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm not sure whether this is a bug, but the behavior definitely is weird. The PHP relative time formats are really powerful, but the following output did surprise me:

```
var_dump(new \DateTime("last day of March +1 month"));
var_dump(new \DateTime("31 March +1 month"));
```

Results into:

```
object(DateTime)#10617 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-04-30 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" } 
object(DateTime)#10617 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-05-01 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }
```

The problem lies in the second `var_dump`, I'm aware that April has 30 days and that is the reason why the output is June 1, but I'd expect it to take that relativity into account, as it does with the first `var_dump`.

So, is this behavior documented somewhere? Or is this actually a bug in PHP?

Comment: The relativity is different because `31 March` is an ___explicit___ (absolute) date plus a relative 1 month to give 31 April (which then adjusts to 1st May as a valid date); whereas `last day of March` is a ___relative___ date, adjusted by a relative 1 month to give the equivalent of `last day of April`

Comment: Actually this behaviour is [described](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) (see section "Beware when adding or subtracting months"). That was [suggested](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55792) in bug tracker to change the date to the first day of the month, add or subtract the number of months desired, than change the date to the last day of that month.

Comment: June is month 6 in gregorian calendar so the output "2016-05-01 00:00:00.000000" actually relates to the month before june which is called may. :-)

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for pointing to both the docs and bug report. Actually I can't think of a situation where you woud prefer it to be June 1, so don't understand why the bug is not fixed yet.

Comment: The "bug" isn't fixed because it isn't considered a bug, it's considered designed and documented behaviour, whether you agree with that diagnosis or not